# Масштабируемость WinForms интерфейса

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как решаются проблемы масштабируемости WinForms C# приложения, когда, например, на более низком разрешении приложении выглядит громоздким?
У меня были некоторые идеи:

-Умножать или делить размер компонентов. Тогда рискую испортить компоненты, которые отображают шрифты.

-Под каждое разрешение сделать свою процедуру инициализации формы и дергать свою версию в зависимости от разрешения.

Может есть какие-то более грамотные решения?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не злоупотребляйте метками. [tag:windows] и [tag:ооп] не имеют никакого отношения к этому вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужна красивая масштабируемость, лучше использовать WPF, там размеры задаются в независимых от разрешения величинах.

Если нужен именно WinForms, то придется пилить свой велосипед для масштабирования под разные разрешения. В WinForms графика на GDI+, а он использует экранные пиксели для указания размера элементов и вычисления размера шрифтов.

С размерами элементов еще можно справиться с помощью `TableLayoutPanel`, указывая высоту строк и ширину столбцов в процентах, а вот шрифты придется руками подгонять.

Comment: Действительно, если это не задача а школе/ВУЗе, то почему бы не использовать WPF, он по многим параметрам лучше, возможностей больше

Answer (score 1):

В винде есть такая настройка как DPI монитора. Пользователи, которым интерфейсы кажутся слишком мелкими, могут ее подкрутить. А вот сделать интерфейс мельче, к сожалению, стандартными средствами нельзя (но, возможно, это можно поправить где-нибудь в реестре).

В WinForms изменение DPI приведет к изменению размеров всех шрифтов, а при установленном AutoScaleMode (установлено по умолчанию) - это изменит еще и размеры всех элементов.

Будьте аккуратнее с TableLayoutPanel, если вы используете автоматическое определение размеров колонок. Их перекосит из-за того, что настройки DPI будут применены два раза. Отключайте AutoScaleMode для TableLayoutPanel с автоматическими строками или колонками.

Comment: DPI в винде вроде на все сразу влияет, а не на конкретное приложение. Хотя в целом тоже важный момент

Comment: @rdorn ну так и надо делать приложение "как все". А если пользователю не будет нравиться сразу все - то он DPI поменяет.

Comment: Кто ж спорит, я лично всеми конечностями за то чтобы приложения выглядели относительно одинаково, и не только в плане масштаба. Иначе у "продвинутого" пользователя ступор и паника случается, когда он не находит привычную кнопочку на привычном месте. Сколько шума было когда изменили интерфейс офиса, некоторые до сих пор негодуют.